# how to generate response for webhook get request

Tags: php, get

I received a get request from a site to my site.  I can able to know what kind of request by using  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].  Its returning GET request.  Now, i need to know how to know what is the request and also generate response for the request in php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For reading the request do the following:

```
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
```

Then to respond you can simply echo back like:

```
echo "I've received your request"
```

Or you can respond with empty headers. Forexample PayPal doesn't require you to respond with anything just send back the 200 header like:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

If the received data is in Json format then you can process it's contents by doing something like:

```
$json = json_decode($webhookContent, true);
```

If that request has a key like webhookname then you can get it by doing:

```
$key = $json['webhookname'];
```

Hope I've covered everything.

Comment: Hi Sohrab. Actually, i reading a request from hubspot webhook, i cannot able to read the get request even after using your code.

Comment: How do you know you are not able to read the request? Try doing: `file_put_contents("content.txt", $webhookContent)`.
And then check the content of the file content.txt

Comment: i am trying to send response to hubspot, i don't know in what format have to send.  Whatever the request may be, no problem.

Comment: So you are reading the request? What do you have to respond with? Which webhook are you referring to specifically?

Comment: get type in this url http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/Workflows/How-do-I-use-webhooks-with-HubSpot-Workflows